# Checkbox WPforms not visible mobile

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, wpforms

WP FORMS:

Suddenly checkboxes are not visible on mobile anymore.
See added pictures mobile / PC ... already tried several CSS codes, but none of them seems to work..
[PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1lPy.jpg)
[MOBILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQysF.jpg)

Please help.

Already tried several CSS codes, please help me